# How to encode a 16bit unsigned integer using IEEE754 format

Tags: bitwise-operators, ieee-754, 16-bit, unsigned-integer

I have a 16 bit unsigned integer and I want to encode it using the standard IEEE754 format

How can I do that?

I found this code online, could it be any useful?

```
uint float_from_int(int x)
{
    if (x == 0)
        return 0; // 0 is a special case because it has no 1 bits

    // Save the sign bit of the input and take the absolute value of the input.
    uint signBit = 0;
    uint absX = (uint)x;
    if (x < 0)
    {
        signBit = 0x80000000u;
        absX = (uint)-x;
    }

    // Shift the input left until the high order bit is set to form the mantissa.
    // Form the floating exponent by subtracting the number of shifts from 158.
    uint exponent = 158;
    while ((absX & 0x80000000) == 0)
    {
        exponent--;
        absX <<= 1;
    }

    // compute mantissa
    uint mantissa = absX >> 8;

    // Assemble the float from the sign, mantissa, and exponent.
    return signBit | (exponent << 23) | (mantissa & 0x7fffff);
}
```

**EDIT**

I adapted the code for the unsigned int case

```
uint float_from_int(uint absX)
{
    if (absX == 0)
        return 0; // 0 is a special case because it has no 1 bits

    uint signBit = 0x00000000u;

    // Shift the input left until the high order bit is set to form the mantissa.
    // Form the floating exponent by subtracting the number of shifts from 158.
    uint exponent = 158;
    while ((absX & 0x80000000) == 0)
    {
        exponent--;
        absX <<= 1;
    }

    // compute mantissa
    uint mantissa = absX >> 8;

    // Assemble the float from the sign, mantissa, and exponent.
    return signBit | (exponent << 23) | (mantissa & 0x7fffff);
}
```

Comment: What happened when you tried it ?

Comment: I didn't because that's for signed int

Comment: Right, but it should be quite easy to adapt it for unsigned - did you try it ? Or you could just use a normal C cast - that would probably be more efficient on most modern CPUs.

Comment: yes, I think I can pass absX straight

Comment: check my edit please

Comment: Well you could get rid of the `signBit` stuff as well, but otherwise it looks promising - why not try it with some test values ?